# Refactoring to Abstract Class

Tags: java, oop, abstract

I got a new task to change some code into something more object oriented, similar to a task asked before.

I am reading a config file and get an Array ar[]. That ar[4] contains week, month, quarter or year. This is done with some bad programmatical skills

```
if (ar[4].equals("week")) {
    weekThreshold();
} else if (ar[4].equals("month")) {
    monthThreshold();
} else if (ar[4].equals("quarter")) {
    quarterThreshold();
} else if (ar[4].equals("year")) {
    yearThreshold();
}
```

Two of those methods called are like this

```
public void weekThreshold() {
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(cal.getTime());

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(cal.getTime());
}

public void monthThreshold() {
    limitGiven = limitGiven * 4;

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(cal.getTime());

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Those variables firstTime and secondTime are finally used in a SQL query.

My task is now to create a Class AbstractThreshold to remove the if/else cases. And from that AbstractThreshold the classes WeekThreshold, MonthThreshold etc.

How can I switch the Threshold methods to an abstract class and make new classes out of those with the right methods again? It is confusing me :(

Comment: Do this short tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html then update your question with what you have tried

Comment: You need to try first. Then come here and ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely more suited for something like [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but i'll give it a go:

I would first try to determine what these objects have in common, in your case it is `firstTime` & `lastTime`, so following that we can construct an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class DateThreshold {

    private final Calendar initial;

    // you can also have a string constructor here to parse your date
    protected DateThreshold(final Date date) {
        this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.calendar.setTime(date);
    }

    private Calendar getInitial() {
        return (Calendar) this.initial.clone();
    }

    public abstract Calendar getStartDate();

    public abstract Calendar getEndDate();
}
```

Now you can start implementing the different types of thresholds, for instance:

```
public static DateThreshold weekThreshold(final Date date) {
    return new RelativeDate(date) {

        @Override
        public Calendar getStartDate() {
            final Calendar cal = super.getCalendar();

            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
            return (Calendar) cal;
        }

        @Override
        public Calendar getEndDate() {
            final Calendar cal = super.getCalendar();

            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
            return (Calendar) cal;
        }
    };
}
```

And to use your new `DateThreshold` you can do this:

```
final DateThreshold week = weekThreshold(new Date());
week.getStartDate();
week.getEndDate();
```

This is obviously untested, but should give you a good idea

Comment: I'll give it a try, looks fantastic at first sight, but are you sure with the private finale Calendar? I actually get a problem with the final. Also, the name from initial is not used in the DateThreshold Method :)

Answer (score 0):

The *normal* refactor for this kind of antipattern is to introduce an `enum`.

```
enum Threshold {

    Week {

                @Override
                void getThreshold() {
                }
            },
    Month {

                @Override
                void getThreshold() {
                }
            },
    Quarter {

                @Override
                void getThreshold() {
                }
            },
    Year {

                @Override
                void getThreshold() {
                }
            };

    abstract void getThreshold();

    private static Map<String, Threshold> thresholds = new HashMap<>();

    static Threshold lookup(String name) {
        if (thresholds.isEmpty()) {
            // Populate.
            for (Threshold t : Threshold.values()) {
                thresholds.put(t.name().toLowerCase(), t);
            }
        }
        return thresholds.get(name);
    }
}

public void test() {
    String[] ar = {"A", "B", "c", "5", "week"};
    Threshold.lookup(ar[4]).getThreshold();
}
```

You can now implemet each of your code fragments in the `enum`.